# Attach excel workbook to an word document

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am new to the Apache Poi library. I am trying to attach an Excel workbook to an existing Word document at a particular place, but I did not get any examples of this. I need to stick with the Apache POI library; is there a way to do this in Java using POI?

I have checked a couple of examples using the Aspose API or the spire.doc library, but these are paid libraries.